# Facebook API - How to do that

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook post button in my game, but its not functioning correctly (Not really doing what I want). I have messed around with the parameters passed to the api I call this way (Android facebook sdk):

```
FacebookManager.this.mFacebook.request("me/feed", params, "POST"); //params is Bundle
```

But I didn't manage to make it function as I want.

What I want is like the following (I don't know why it shows error image, buts lets say it did not)

[image: Example]

I know that the RED message is the "message" parameter. About the rest - what are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The red is "message".

Yellow is "picture" - a url.

Blue is both "link" - where to go redirect when user clicks, and "name" - whats actually displayed.

Purple is "description".

Used the [facebook graph api explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to find out how to do so.