# how to post highest score in facebook wall (android + facebook)

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing an android game integrated with facebook api. how can is post my score in game to facebook wall.

I looked at open graph but could not figure out how to make it work.

Cheers, 
T_T

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [ask] to learn how to formulate a good question that will get good answers. You must show what you have done (code), and what errors you are getting, otherwise people are just going to give you links to the FB graph API (general answers for general questions)

Answer (score 6):

That's the code I use:

```
    final Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("message", "message to show on the user's wall");
    params.putString("picture", "picture url");
    params.putString("link", "link - (I put market link here)");
    params.putString("name", "Link name");
    params.putString("description", "description bellow the link");
```

Then call:

```
this.mFacebook.request("me/feed", params, "POST");
```

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142297/facebook-api-how-to-do-that).