# Can't publish a high score to player's timeline on Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a PHP game and would like to post players highscores to their own facebook wall /timeline.

I've set up a Facebook App and the PHP code I'm using to POST the score is (as provided by Facebook itself):

```
<?php
 require 'facebook-sdk/facebook.php';

 $app_id = MY_APP_ID;
 $app_secret = MY_APP_SECRET;
 $score = 1500;  // this is gonna be passed someway...

 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
   'appId'  => $app_id,
   'secret' => $app_secret,
 ));

 $user = MY_USER_ID;  // to be replaced with a call to $facebook->getUser()

 $app_access_token = get_app_access_token($app_id, $app_secret);
 $facebook->setAccessToken($app_access_token);
 $response = $facebook->api('/' . $user . '/scores', 'post', array(
   'score' => $score,
 ));
 print($response);

 // Helper function to get an APP ACCESS TOKEN
 function get_app_access_token($app_id, $app_secret) {
   $token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?'
     . 'client_id=' . $app_id
     . '&client_secret=' . $app_secret
     . '&grant_type=client_credentials';

   $token_response =file_get_contents($token_url);
   $params = null;
   parse_str($token_response, $params);
   return  $params['access_token'];
 }
?>
```

Of course there is a login and install section which I have omitted, asking the user to login and grant '`publish_stream`' and '`publish_actions`' privileges to the app.

This is working with success, the response variable outputs 1.
I can see the posted score using the Facebook Graph API Explorer so I assume everything is really working fine and smooth.

The problem is that I am not able to see the supposedly posted user-story anywhere on Facebook.
Reading the documentation it seems to me that a user story has to be automatically published when one saves a score. As an example, have a look [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/03/05/games-update--expanding-distribution-for-scores-and-achievements/) or [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/games/getting-started/#step4).

Does anyone solved this problem already? Do you see something that I might have missing? Can you please point me at the right direction to solve this issue?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: did you check in activity log? You can accees it through https://www.facebook.com/USER_ID/allactivity

Comment: Are you sure you're using a valid app access token? (i.e. try `echo`ing it out and making sure it is what you expect) Have you tried replicating the request in the [Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)?

Comment: Unfortunately I did both, as I wrote: the score does gets saved by Facebook but no post is appearing anywhere as I expected from the docs.

Comment: have you posted score for a test user or real user?

Comment: Please do not post solutions or ideas just googled and not tested. I mean: facebook.com/USER_ID/allactivity is not working. Facebook responds with a 'Page Not Found'. Thanks

Comment: user_id has to replaced with your id

Comment: I know, man. It's a Page Not Found.

Comment: I have timeline enabled for my account. You can see this for my account https://www.facebook.com/Venu.T/allactivity . if you have username, that should be used

Comment: Is your app's category set to 'Games"? Only apps with this category setting can publish score stories. You can check this setting on FB Developer pages > Apps > Your app name > Edit Settings > Category.

Comment: Yes it is a Game indeed. Score IS saved but does not appear as a score story anywhere on Facebook

Comment: You might have read this already, but your question seems similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817421/facebook-score-api-calls-from-android-not-displaying-high-scores-on-timeline-tic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You write

> Reading the documentation it seems to me that a user story has to be automatically published when one saves a score.

Scores are not automatically published. They are only published under certain conditions, namely when a user:

- gets a new high score ("High score story").
- pass another friend's score("Passing story").

In your code you post the score 1,500 everytime. After the first time you post it, when you post it again repeatedly for testing, your post request will be successful but the score will not be published again since it is not a new high.

Sources:
[Facebook Developers: Games Tutorial.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/games/)
[Facebook Developers Developer Blog: Games Update: Expanding distribution for Scores and Achievements](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/03/05/games-update--expanding-distribution-for-scores-and-achievements/)

Comment: My development has gone further, now I'm posting both as a score and as a wall post.
So I'm no longer posting always 1,500 and I am checking the actual score to be greater than what's stored on Facebook before posting.
While I'm writing I'm doing some test with a couple of friends, will let you know

Comment: Update time: following to tests I made with my friends, I have to say that this is partially working. I was able to get the "Passing story" only three times out of five and I never got a "High score story". Do you have any further suggestion and/or explanation? So, far you're the best answer. Accepted :)

Comment: Glad it helped:) Based on your description of your tests, I think high score stories are filtered for frequency internally at FB so that these stories don't appear too often in a user's feed. For example, several new high score posts on a single day from a player playing your game would not be published. The details of how this filter operates appear to be private

Answer (score 2):

Try look at this

https://github.com/fbsamples/CriticalMass/tree/master/web/criticalmass

Hope will be a useful

Comment: Already studied before posting. My code is derived from that, and is not working still

Answer (score 1):

You can create a post on an application's profile page by issuing an HTTP POST request to APP_ID/feed (not PROFILE_ID/posts) with the publish_stream permissions.

More Details : [TechNew.In](http://www.technew.in)

Comment: Ok, but this doesn't solve the question. Looks more like a workaround, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is 'When I successfully post a score to the API, it doesn't necessarily create a story in News Feed or on Timeline' this isn't a problem - this is how the scores API works.

Scores are a lightweight sharing option, and aren't always shown individually - i rarely see 'User got score X' stories on Facebook, but see 'X beat Y's Score in Z' and 'X got a new high score' fairly often - There's also a Timeline unit on a user's profile showing a summary of gaming activity and the scores data is shown there.

Just keep posting to /[user]/scores when the user gets a new high score and let Facebook take care of the distribution

Answer (score 0):

I read something recently that FB has stopped allowing Api posts to timelines. It will still show up in the news feed but just not on their wall anymore.

Comment: Can you please post some link? 'I read something' is quite generic, isn't it?

Answer (score -2):

I think i've found the issue for you.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/#types

See the statement:

Pages of type article or video do not have publishing rights, and will not show up on user's profiles because they are not real world objects.